# Sympy "not equal" equation

Tags: python, math, sympy, algebra

Is there any way to solve algebra equations that contain ≠?

for example: 2-x ≠ 3

So, may be it looks like this:

```
print(solve(not_equal(2-x, 3)))
```

Comment: Can't you just use an equal eqation solver and then take the inverse of that result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Unequality` class to represent the "not equal", or its alias `Ne`. For example:

```
print(solve(Ne(2-x, 3)))
# out: (x > -oo) & (x < oo) & Ne(x, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should solve the == equation and take complement of the solution in the reals.

You can also try to solve inequation < and > and take the union of the solution sets.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).